# Automatically add code to custom subclasses

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos

If I create a subclass of one of Apple's classes, ie: UIViewController, it comes with some methods already defined in the implementation file, ie: -viewDidLoad.

Is there a way to do this with my own classes?

I have been searching for the answer but haven't come up with anything.

**Edit: To clarify my Question**
I know how to subclass & use protocols etc.
What I want to do is have important methods that should be overridden by a subclass written into the implementation file automatically.

Better example:
If you subclass UITableViewController you will need to implement
-numberOfSections...
-numberOfRows...
-cellForRowAtIndex...
But you don't have to write them yourself, Apple automatically adds them into the file.

So is there something in obj-c that allows me to do that with my classes or is that something Apple has baked into xcode that can only be done by them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are basically boiler plate code which is written when the IDE is being designed itself.

Comment: Thats what I wanted to know. , so not something I can do then. Thanks for your answer.